# Is it inappropriate to announce the upcoming molad prior to Shabbat?

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, molad

Our shul (like many others) has a weekly e-mail newsletter that goes out before Shabbat containing candlelighting times, davening times, etc., as well as information on simchas and upcoming community events.

It occurred to me this week that perhaps on the Shabbat before Rosh Chodesh we should include the molad in the newsletter.  Then it occurred to me that perhaps we should *not* do so, because the molad is supposed to be announced at Birchat ha-chodesh, and it might be inappropriate to announce it prematurely.  And then it occurred to me that even if that were the case, printing it in a newsletter might not count as an "announcement".

Are there any actual issues here, or is this a "do whatever you want" situation?

Comment: "Announcing the molad" before Birchat ha-chodesh only became a thing pretty recently, and plenty of communities don't do it at all.

Comment: There is no reason not to announce the molad before shabbos but on the other hand there is no reason to announce the molad before shabbos

Comment: OU Torah Tidbits, which is distributed to 30,000 copies in Israel every Shabbat, has printed the molad for as long as I can remember, many years for sure. I can't see an issue with doing it

Answer (score 1):

In the Stolin-Karlin siddur it actually encourages the individual to know the molad *before* it's announced.

Comment: More generally, the announcement of the molad is just to make sure everyone knows it before the announcement of the date of rosh chodesh. If you know that everyone knows the molad already there is no reason to announce.